# Regex OR matching stuff that I dont want

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP.

I have a strings like:

```
example.123.somethingelse
example.1234.somethingelse
example.2015.123.somethingelse
example.2015.1234.somethingelse
```

and I came up with this regex

```
/example\.(2015\.|)([0-9]{3,4})\./
```

What I want to get is "123" or "1234" and it works for these strings. But when the string is

```
example.2015.A01.somethingelse
```

the result is "2015".

The way that I see it, after "2015." I have "A" and this should not be matched by the regex, but it is ( and I suppose there is a solid reason for it that I dont understand atm).

How can I fix it ( make the regex match nothing since the last string does not follow the same structure as the others) ?

Comment: Does that "somethingelse" part contain periods? If not, writing a regular expression that always matches the entire string (starting with `^`, ending with `$`) may be a solution.

Comment: Nice question. Here's a "complex" solution: https://regex101.com/r/hF1tN6/2 . You might need to use `explode()` to fetch the numbers out. Not much time to explain it in details so I left it as a comment... That said, maybe you could better use a general regex and divide the task in simpler phases. The above regex can create quite a shock to people unfamiliar with regex :)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is this:

```
/example\.(2015\.|)([0-9]{3,4})\./
```

That says

- First match "example" followed by a period
- Then match either "2015" followed by a period OR nothing at all.
- Then match 3 or 4 digits in a row followed by a period

When you have the string `example.2015.A01.somethingelse` it matches the `"example.2015."` but then, as you said, the `"A"` messes it up so it backtracks and matches just `"example."` (remember the "OR" allowed for *nothing* to be matched). So it matches `"example."` followed by NOTHING followed by 3 or 4 numeric digits -- since `"2015"` is 4 numeric digits it comfortably matches `"example.2015"`.

It's hard to tell from your description, but I think you've just got a mis-placed vertical bar:

```
/example\.(2015\.)|([0-9]{3,4})\./
```

That should match EITHER "example.2015." OR numbers like 123 -- but "2015" is still 4 numeric digits in a row, so it will still match. I don't have a clear enough idea of the pattern to figure out how that could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `\d+` and take the first result in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex, you use the following:

```
(2015\.|)
```

This allows the regex to match either `2015.` **or** the empty string (zero characters).

When the regex `example\.(2015\.|)([0-9]{3,4})\.` is applied to the following example:

```
example.2015.A01.somethingelse
```

it will to match the literal characters `example`, and then the empty string with `(2015\.|)` and then uses `([0-9]{3,4})\.` to match the string `2015`, which is 4 numerical characters. Thus your expression matches the following:

```
example.2015.
```

Comment: if I remove the "|" symbol it would not match "example.123.somethingelse"

Comment: Do you not want the `A01` to qualify as part of your `somethingelse`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
/example\.(2015\.)?+([0-9]{3,4})\./
```

The `2015.` is still optional, but once the regex has matched it, it won't give it up, even if that causes the match to fail.  I'm assuming the substring you're trying to capture with `([0-9]{3,4})` can never have the value `2015`.  That is, you won't need to match something like this:

```
    example.2015.somethingelse
```

If that's not the case, it's going to be much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

here is one more pattern

```
example\.(?:2015\.)?\K(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/228)

or to your specific amount of digits

```
example\.(?:2015\.)?\K(\d{3,4})
```